# iOS tracking location while walking

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, geolocation, mapkit

Hi Friends i am new to `iOS` App development. I am working on iOS application in which i want to implement tracking feature.

It means user can start tracking from where he is standing currently & then continue show path where he is going draw that on `Mapview`.

I have tried google it but i am not getting idea about how i can draw continuous path while walking by adding continuous Lat-Long to it.

Can anyone suggest me how can i implement this?

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Try Apple's Breadcrumb sample.

Answer (score 1):

Read up the documentation on the CLLocationManager:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html

And MKMapview:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html

You will most likely want to use the CLLocationManagerDelegate method to get updates about the user's location:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

You will also want to implement the MKMapViewDelegate to annotate the view with the user's current location:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
```

I hope this points you in the right direction.